# Android SDK Manager - Android R and S Preview, Android 10.0+

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-manager

Several question about SDK manager and API versions.

What's the difference below API version and when use some of them?

```
Android R Preview  - Api R
Android S Preview  - Api S
Android 10.0 + R   - Api 30
```

Android 10.0 + R is API for android 11 and under version?